# Vue 3, $emit never firing

Tags: vue.js

The documentation is not enough to be able to do the emit. I have seen many tutorials and nothing works, now I am testing this

**Child component**

```
<div @click="$emit('sendjob', Job )"></div>
```

With the Vue DevTools plugin I can see that the data is sent in the PayLoad, but I can't find a way to receive this emit from the other component.
Many people do this

**Any other component**

```
<template>
  <div @sendjob="doSomething"></div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
     methods:{
        doSomething(){
           console.log('It works')
        }
     }
  }
</script>
```

In my case it doesn't work

Comment: I assume you meant `<child-component @sendjob="doSomething" />` and not `<div @sendjob="doSomething"></div>`?

Comment: Elaborating on the above. `$emit` denotes a parent -> child relationship, where the `child` wants to tell the parent that something has happened. Simply emitting within the parent will not result in the parent capturing the `$emit` and would require a parent implementing the component that performs the `$emit` to create the round trip.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import the child component in the parent component and use it instead of the regular `div` tag.

I'm sharing examples for your reference to achieve emits in Vue 3 using `<script setup>` and Composition API. I strongly suggest going with `<script setup` if you are going to use Composition API in Single File Component. However, the choice is yours.

Example with `<script setup>`: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

```js
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
  <UserDetail @user-detail-submitted="userDetailSubmitted"/>
</template>

<script setup>
import UserDetail from './components/UserDetail';

function userDetailSubmitted(name) {
  console.log({ name })
}
</script>

<!-- UserDetail.vue -->
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="name" @keyup.enter="$emit('user-detail-submitted', name)" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const name = ref('');
</script>
```

Example using Composition API: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html

```js
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
  <UserDetail @user-detail-submitted="userDetailSubmitted"/>
</template>

<script>
import UserDetail from "./components/UserDetail";

export default {
  components: {
    UserDetail,
  },

  setup() {
    function userDetailSubmitted(name) {
      console.log({ name });
    }

    return {
      userDetailSubmitted
    }
  },
};
</script>

<!-- UserDetail.vue -->
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="name" @keyup.enter="$emit('user-detail-submitted', name)" />
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const name = ref('');

    return {
      name,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The examples work perfectly, thank you very much. The first one is really easy to setup

Comment: It works on a new empty project, but in main project when i add "const name = ref(''); " gives me an error on the component Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at eval (DevJobCard.vue?eeb3:16)

Comment: And the second gives me "export 'ref' was not found in 'vue'

Comment: Could you please confirm the version of Vue that you are using?

The script setup is introduced after Vue 3.2 or like that.

Comment: The fault was mine, I installed vue via console by a command that a youtuber used, the configuration was very different from the one provided by "create" of vue-cli, maybe it was an older version. I installed vue-cli with npm and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should import this child-component in the parent. And don't rename it to the html's original tag.vue3. You'd better use the Composition API.